# How to find the length between two points or a whole graph of a function?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

You are given $f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a function such as $3x^4-6x^2-4x+2$. You are asked to find the length of the curve between two points $(a,f(a)) \text{ and } (b,f(b))$. How would I do this for:

- Polynomials $3x^2, 4x^3-5x^2-x+2$
- Exponentials $e^x, 5^x$
- Rationals $\dfrac{x+1}{x},\dfrac{3x^2-5x+2}{x^2+2x+2}$
- Logarithmic $\ln x, \log x^3$
- Trigonometric $4\sin x, 5\cos x$

Comment: Also, try looking at [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged calculus:

The length of a curve for a differentiable function from $a$ to $b$:

$$
L=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx
$$